# How can I detect focus lost in mintty under Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

Does [mintty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mintty) under Cygwin in any way support the events of losing and gaining focus?

I'm looking for the equivalent of `WM_KILLFOCUS` from Windows or `autocmd FocusLost * call ...` from `gvim`, but under Cygwin within the mintty terminal.

Comment: You can use `GetForegroundWindow` and a loop to detect change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided there was no actual answer after a few days, I'm providing my own, thanks to @Philippe's comment about [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow).

```
/* wait-focus-lost.cc */
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const HWND initial_window = GetForegroundWindow();
    HWND current_window;
    while ((current_window = GetForegroundWindow()) == initial_window)
        Sleep(1);
    const auto title = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH*2];
    GetWindowTextW(current_window, title, MAX_PATH*2);
    std::wcout << title << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>*Disclaimer: no error checking in above code*</sup>

This piece of code waits until the foreground window changes and prints out [the title of the new foreground window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowinfo) to the `mintty` console.

I can now use this executable in a `bash` script to wait before executing another action that depends on focus being stolen.

---

Since my environment is Cygwin, I'm providing the Makefile in case someone comes along and tries to compile the above on their own:

```
CXX = x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
CC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
LDFLAGS = -static
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wextra

all: wait-focus-lost.exe
wait-focus-lost.exe: wait-focus-lost
```

<sup>*NB: Because of the `.exe` extension, the extra rule is needed under Cygwin to leverage **both** `make` [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) **and** dependency checking. Using just `all: wait-focus-lost` works for compilation, but breaks dependency checking.*</sup>